# perforce: how to add a file with writing permissions

Tags: file, perforce, chmod

I'm trying to find a way of adding ( p4 add ) a file that will have a chmod 660 permissions.
( I'm using a p4 command-line, not p4v ) ?

Since Perforce is treating file extensions differently, maybe it matters if I say that the file is a local, simple, .log file.

I can't create the file on the fly through the script because the directory is also controlled by Perforce and its permissions issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the +w filetype modifier: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/file.types.html

For example, a file of type "text+w" will always be made writable when the p4 client (or p4v, or any other Perforce client tool) syncs it from the server.

Comment: I saw this modifier but it still doesn't work the way I expect, I need a rw-rw-rw- and perforce gives me rw-r--r--